# Fluent NHibernate delegate mapping Func

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Given this (HORRIBLE) object graph that I can't change

```
public class Email
{
    public Email(string email) { ... }
    //DO a bunch of worthless stuff
}

public interface IPerson
{
    Email Email{get;set;}
}
```

Does something like this exist?

```
Map(p => p.EmailAddress).Use(s => new EmailAddress(s));
```

Essentially the Person interface won't take a string and I don't own the Email class so I can't modify it...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Fluent NHibernate, but you can create your own `IUserType` which will map from `Email` to `string` and vice versa. It's real easy: see [this](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It is called component and useful for mapping valuetypes like an emailaddress.